# Firefox: Temporarily disable any Links / Tabs from opening

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox and I want to temporarily disable any links from opening, be it in a new tab, the same tab or another window. Neither by actively clicking on a Hyperlink nor by a JavaScript function should another link be opened.

What I mean by "temporarily" is, that there would be some kind of button or configuration in about:config I can use to turn this behaviour on and off.

- Is there a built-in functionality I can use for this purpose?
- Is there any extension which can do this?
- How difficult would it be to write my own extension if no such extension exists yet?
- In case none of the above are viable options: is there some way to reconfigure Firefox on my own to build-in such a functionality?

Thank you. Any and all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by harrymc there is an addon called [Popupblocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popupblockerall/) which can be set to prevent all new windows or tabs from opening.

Comment: It's customary to credit the person who gave the answer.

Comment: How do I do that? just write their name as part of the answer or is there some kind of "official" way of giving credit?

Comment: Just accept my answer. You are not obliged to put up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the
[Greasemonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
with the
[Disable window.open userscript](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/123115):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable window.open
// @namespace      https://userscripts-mirror.org/users/113106
// @description    Disables window.open (to prevent pop-ups and pop-unders)
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==
window.open = function() {};
```

To enable or disable, do enable or disable of the Greasemonkey add-on.

Some popups find very creative solutions to avoid such measures.

Try the
[Popupblocker add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popupblockerall/),
which uses more than just the above method.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I want. These settings still allow new tabs to be opened, it only prevents them from being opened in a new window.

Comment: I thought the option of "force new window into same tab" is the one you wanted. If you would like to disable clicks on links, that's another matter.

Comment: But that still opens the link itself. It just overwrites the current tab with another one. I want the javascript function Window.Open (and any similar functionality within the browser) to become a no-op.

Comment: Fine, here is another option.

Comment: Tried it and it didnt work. Do you have any idea what could be missing?

Comment: Try using `window` instead of `unsafeWindow`.

Comment: still didnt work. The website was still able to open 2 new tabs as I clicked a div-element.

Comment: Is this about blocking popups? Some of them find very creative solutions to avoid such measures. Try for example the [Popupblocker add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popupblockerall/).

Comment: I tried various add-ons like NoScript, Adblock Plus, UBlock Origin, etc and so far this particular site managed to open tabs still. Except when all scripts are disabled of course, but that disables the functionality as well. I have not tried using Popupblocker yet. Maybe I will give it a try.

Comment: the addon Popupblocker that you suggested has actually worked! Thank you very much.